# about using global variable or local variable in recursion

Tags: python

Hi recently I encountered a subtle issue while trying to build a Trie function:

```
def search(self, word):
    def dfs(node, word):
        if not word:
            if node.end:
                self.res = True
            return
        if word[0]!='.':
            node = node.next.get(word[0])
            if not node:
                return
            dfs(node, word[1:])
        else:
            for n in node.next.values():
                dfs(n, word[1:])

    curr = self.root
    self.res = False
    dfs(curr, word)
    return self.res
```

This works.

But this doesn't:

```
def search(self, word):
    def dfs(node, word, res):
        if not word:
            if node.end:
                res = True
            return
        if word[0]!='.':
            node = node.next.get(word[0])
            if not node:
                return
            dfs(node, word[1:], res)
        else:
            for n in node.next.values():
                dfs(n, word[1:], res)

    curr = self.root
    res = False
    dfs(curr, word, res)
    return res
```

I don't get it why the latter approach, which passes a variable along the recursion instead of using a global variable, does not work.

Comment: Because assigning to a parameter doesn't change the variable at the call site. Though you don't need a "global" in either case, as `dfs` is a nested function

Comment: What is the error traceback you are getting on the latter?

Comment: because the value of `res` changes during each recursive call and is not stored anywhare, unlike `self.res`. You can make the second example work correctly byassigning the `res` to some global state

Answer (score 1):

The issue has to do with the way objects are handled and passed to functions in Python. Inside the function `res` is a new variable, initialized to the object the function was called with. But assigning `res = True` inside the function just means `res` now names a different object. It doesn't change the object in the callers scope.  As a simple example imagine this code:

```
def Test(result):
  if (something):
     result = True

Test(False) 

#what would I check to see if result changed?
#is the global False constant now equal to True?
```

I can see a few ways around your problem.

1. Return `res` from the function. `res = dfs(n, word, res)`
2. Pass an array, whose contents can be modified inside a function.  `res = [True]` would make res name a different array, but `res[0] = True` changes a value inside the original array.

Like this.

```
res = [False]
dfs(n, word, res)
...
return res[0]
```

3- Use the `nonlocal` keyword to use a variable in a higher scope:

```
def search(self, word):
    res = False
    def dfs(node, word):
        nonlocal res #this is the same object as the `res` in `search`
        if not word:
            if node.end:
                res = True #this will modify `res` as intended
        ... #rest of dfs function

    dfs(self.root, word)
    return res
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/52548178/10396 and related questions to understand pass-by-value vs. pass-by-reference.

Comment: *Everything* in Python is passed by value. The issue is whether you try to mutate the object referenced by that value (where mutation is distinct from simple assignment to a name.)

Comment: Since `dfs` is a nested function in OPs code you should also mention the option of using `nonlocal res`

Comment: TIL about `nonlocal`. Thanks.